# What are some awesome personal statements for careers?

Tags: discussion, jobs, fun

Turns out careers really wants me to type in a personal statement. I agree with it and think its really important.... but lack inspiration at the moment.

Would you have some ideas for some cool personal statements I could draw inspiration from?

"I like waffles" is just not going to cut it.

I really like this question, so I will [share a tip](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=site%3Acareers.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: My sticking point is how long the personal statement should be. A sentence or two? One paragraph? Two paragraphs?

Comment: I have no idea, thats why I need inspiration, I guess the recruiters will be reading this so it can not be too long...

Comment: I have always heard that you want to keep it short and to the point.  One small paragraph I would assume is what most want to see.

Comment: Make it short and sweet, like "Two waffles with syrup."

Comment: I think you ruined this question by using "I like waffles" as your example. haha

Comment: @troggy, I blame Iceland

Comment: You can't really avoid waffles though with a name like that. ;)

Comment: waffles is here to stay ....

Comment: Isn't Careers a proper noun?

Answer (score 27):

Some interesting public CVs:

- http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ptomblin
- http://careers.stackoverflow.com/swilliams
- http://careers.stackoverflow.com/lobrien
- http://careers.stackoverflow.com/puls
- http://careers.stackoverflow.com/george-stocker

The prize for the best waffle out there goes to:

- http://careers.stackoverflow.com/michal

Tips to make it **awesome**:

Keep it short

Formatting is super *dooper* important
 
You love to code, find a way to say it
 
**bold** but **don't use too much bold**
Make somebody smile, keep it chirpy

Comment: +1, good tips, good links.  -1, not a haiku.

Comment: is using **bold** a good idea for a personal statement (and in general in written text)? Perhaps _italic_? None?

Comment: Three links are obsolete, invisible to users with <10K.

Answer (score 10):

**My personal statement is rather long.** Too long to quote here. You would starve to death before reaching its end.

**My personal statement is rather deep.** The revelations contained within it are too profound for any reader to comprehend in a single reading.

**My personal statement is rather magnificent.** Its magnificence would blind you, burning a hole deep into your brain and leaving you unfit for employment of any sort.

**My personal statement begins like this:**

> I like applesauce on my pizza.

Comment: What a coincidence! Mine starts with "Shog9 likes applesauce on his pizza."

Comment: You've been copying Jon Skeets personal statements haven't you?

Comment: The main question is: did you get any interest from prospect employers?

Answer (score 5):

Mine talks about riding the subway without p[an](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/tomritter)ts.

Comment: "I judge people by what they're produced, then by what they teach, then what they know."  I think you meant "they've"?

Answer (score 3):

<strike>"I am awesome, I have xxxxx stackoverflow reputation!"</strike>

Haha, had to say it because people get so worked up over reputation, so a serious answer:

I think your personal statement should sum yourself up in a few sentences.  People are not looking for an autobiography here.  Mention some of your best personal qualities, diversity (as in activites/personal/professional life), your desire to continually improve yourself and work with others.

Comment: Only good if you can link to the site and live update your rep.

Comment: @womble: Well in that case you can just say "I am awesome."

Comment: Stop stealing my personal statement!

Comment: Ok ok, jokes over. Serious answer added. haha

Comment: You weren't exactly loving those downvotes, were you?  Love them, Troggy!  Love them and set them free!

Comment: @Pollyanna: People were doing what they should.  I deserved every single one for my original answer.

Answer (score 1):

"I like providing simple solutions to perplexing puzzles to people."

Answer (score 0):

Hey, man, do you like lasers?

Comment: Hell yeah, but I am not looking jokes here :p. I am looking for some serious

Comment: Oh, then you'd best stick with the other answers about pants and applesauce.

Answer (score 0):

Here's mine:

Software development as the DRY KISS of YAGNI