# Examples of good resumes

Tags: support, jobs

I wanted to write a resume on careers. It seems clear for me that the format of the resume is not very "traditional".

Can I ask for links to a few resumes you consider "well written" so that I can see the usual level of professionalism vs. friendliness, average length, etc?

I don't want to copy them or anything, I just want to make sure mine is too/not enough professional/long/boring/funny/etc compared to others.

Comment: see also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30709/what-are-some-awesome-personal-statements-for-careers